# How to read the contents of a closed stream?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm intercepting a [`WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) object in a WSE 2.0 proxy class (`Microsoft.Web.Services2` package) and attempting to read the `RequestStream` (made a proxy class around the `WebRequest` that overrides `GetRequestStream()` so I can play with it).

Problem is that I'm getting a `stream is not readable` exception, which seens reasonable because the framework wrote the request and disposed the internal [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx). I wonder, though, when and how does it read the stream for IIS (app pool) to send the request so I can intercept it.

The main question is: How can I get the contents of an "unreadable" stream into a string?
Hackish approaches (like monkey patching framework classes) are welcome too.

PS: Ask for snippets you need on comments.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Assuming the framework uses a `HttpWebRequest` as descendant the actual return type is the abstract `Stream` thing...
I guess I'll have to digg the GetType while debugging to answer that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's a Microsoft.Web.Services2.OutputStream... it has a private member _memoryStream and flags are set for write only.